# Using Django ModelForm with FK

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys, modelform

I will start apologizing for my bad english, it's not my native language. Anyway...
    I am a beginner in Python/Django and I'm tryind to do one form application and I'm not being able to work correctly with ForeignKeys. For example: I got one table named Station and another named Person. In Person Table, I got a Station field that references to Station table. My form works fine, but the display of information doesn't. When I open the the ModelChoiceField, instead of showing names or id of the Station, it show to me in every object: . Is there a way(probably) of defining which field will be appearing on my Form? These are my files:

MODELS.PY:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    station = models.ForeignKey("Station")
    def __unicode__(self):
    return "{0} {1}".format(self.first_name, self.last_name)

class Station(models.Model):
    station_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    def __unicode(self):
    return str(self.station_name)

    FORMS.PY:
    class FormPerson(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
    model = Person
```

VIEWS.PY:

```
def addperson(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
    form = FormPerson(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
    form.save()
    return render_to_response("salvo.html",{})
    else:
    form = FormPerson()
    return render_to_response("adiciona.html", {'form': form},
    context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

ADICIONA.HTML:

```
<form action="" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<button type="submit">Adicionar</button>
</form>
```

Comment: `__unicode` in Station should be `__unicode__` if I understood your question correctly.

Comment: Holy sh*, simples like that. It worked, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo on Station's `__unicode__` method (it's only half-magic ;).

It's must be like:

```
class Station(models.Model):
    station_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.station_name
```